# flutter_bloc 4.0.0 how to get event properties/parametrs

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am quite new to this library and BLOC pattern too, I need fetch all products and a single product based on a particular id.

I have seen many examples created using this library , those people are getting parameter by event.paramter

In my case its not working.

Q. How to get event properties while extending equatable?? inside bloc.

events.dart

```
abstract class ProductsEvent extends Equatable {
  const ProductsEvent();
}
class FetchProducts extends Equatable{
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];

}

class FetchSingleProduct extends Equatable{
  final int id;
 const FetchSingleProduct({@required this.id}) : assert(id !=null);
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id];
}
```

Bloc.dart

```
class ProductsBloc extends Bloc<ProductsEvent, ProductsState> {
  final AbstractProductsRepository abstractProductsRepository;
  ProductsBloc(this.abstractProductsRepository);

  @override
  ProductsState get initialState => InitialProductsState();

  @override
  Stream<ProductsState> mapEventToState(
    ProductsEvent event,

  ) async* {
    yield ProductsLoadingState();
    if(event is FetchProducts){
      try{

        final productsData = await abstractProductsRepository.fetchProducts();
        yield ProductsLoadedState(productsData);
      }on Error{
        print("Error in Block");
        yield ProductErrorState();
      }
    }else if(event is FetchSingleProduct){
      try{

        //Event.id  - not working.
        final productData = await abstractProductsRepository.fetchSingleProduct(**event.id**);
        yield SingleProductLoaded(productData);
      }on Error{
        print("Error in Block");
        yield ProductErrorState();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when you pass event does it entering in any try bloc ?

Comment: Tried adding for both, but none accepting. arguments.

Comment: Thanx @VirenVVarasadiya, My bad , I was extending to equatable for all events instead of event type. By extending Event type Everthing working fine now

Comment: Accept my answer if it is useful.@techieasif

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to extends ProductsEvent

```
abstract class ProductsEvent extends Equatable {
  const ProductsEvent();
}

class FetchProducts extends ProductsEvent {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class FetchSingleProduct extends ProductsEvent {
  final int id;

  const FetchSingleProduct({@required this.id}) : assert(id !=null);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Extend ProductsEvent as below and also you have to pass props to super class.

```
@immutable
abstract class ProductsEvent extends Equatable {
  ProductsEvent([List props = const []]) : super(props);
}

class FetchProducts extends ProductsEvent {
  @override
  String toString() => 'LoadTodos';
}

class FetchSingleProduct extends ProductsEvent {
  final int id;
  AddTodo(this.id) : super([id]);

}
```